# Android: Unable to go back to previous page in Webview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-webview

I'm loading a url in `WebView` which has a flow of 3-4 screens but I'm unable to go back to previous page even if it's available. I'm using below code in the fragment to load url in webview.

```
 binding.webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    binding.webView.settings.minimumFontSize = resources.getInteger(R.integer.webView_small_font_size)
    binding.webView.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    binding.webView.setOnKeyListener(object : View.OnKeyListener {
        override fun onKey(v: View, keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
            if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                val webView = v as WebView
                when (keyCode) {
                    KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK -> if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                        webView.goBack()
                        return true
                    }
                }
            }
            return false
        }
    })

    binding.webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, url: String): Boolean {
            view.loadUrl(WEBVIEW_BASE_URL)
            return true
        }
    }

    binding.webView.loadUrl(WEBVIEW_BASE_URL)
```

I have tried to handle by device back button also but it's not working.

```
private fun handleBack() {
    val callback: OnBackPressedCallback =
        object : OnBackPressedCallback(true /* enabled by default */) {
            override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                if (binding.webView.isFocused && binding.webView.canGoBack()) {
                    binding.webView.goBack()
                } else {
                    mainActivityVM.reset()
                    activity?.finishAffinity()
                }
            }
        }
    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner, callback)
}
```

Please let me know if I'm following any wrong step.

Comment: So what happens, when you press the back button, or try to go back?

Comment: it closes the fragment.